# The compiler failed with error code -1073741502 (SharePoint 2010 SP1 running on Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, compiler-errors, windows-server-2008

I have a virtual machine (running in VMWare Workstation 8.0.2 on my laptop) running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 that I use for SharePoint development (Visual Studio 2010 is installed on the virtual machine). Sometimes I get the following error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service     this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source     code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe"     /t:library /utf8output /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\AscomADManager\1.0.0.0__e27e5c95e5e50246\AscomADManager.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SharePoint.Search\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\App_GlobalResources.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\App_global.asax.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.UI\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.UI.dll" /out:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\App_Web_usereditform.ascx.d7f0a421.emiw9vda.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\q8k8a1mo.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\App_Web_usereditform.ascx.d7f0a421.emiw9vda.0.cs" 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7e9d64cc\e402abe9\App_Web_usereditform.ascx.d7f0a421.emiw9vda.1.cs"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4963; ASP.NET     Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

The error is thrown quite randomly, sometimes when I activate a new feature, sometimes     when I'm just browsing pages/lists in SharePoint. I have of course googled the problem, and I've found some solutions to it that have worked for some other users (but not for all):

- Do an iisreset (doesn't work for me)
- Do an iisreset, then reboot (doesn't work for me)
- Remove ASP.NET temporary files (doesn't work for me)
- Remove ASP.NET temporary files and reboot (doesn't work for me)
- Reinstall (repair) .NET framework (the only solution that works for me)

Does anyone have an idea of a solution that fixes the problem without repairing .NET framework? It's quite time consuming, not to mention frustrating to have to do this all the time. The error occurs anywhere between three to ten times a day.

**Update: This is the warning that is logged in the Windows event log.**

```
Event code: 3007 
Event message: A compilation error has occurred. 
Event time: 4/4/2012 12:48:04 PM 
Event time (UTC): 4/4/2012 10:48:04 AM 
Event ID: ea6ef6e68cb14f858564f541ff1389f6 
Event sequence: 42 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1794141158/ROOT-1-129780060874042968 
    Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ 
    Machine name: SP2010 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 13668 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpCompileException 
    Exception message: External component has thrown an exception. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://sp2010/sites/test52/projects/default.aspx 
    Request path: /sites/test52/projects/default.aspx 
    User host address: fe80::18b5:d6c1:ca34:5476/ 
    User: SP20100\marcus 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 11 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

Comment: Here is someone with the same error (but in HEX instead of DEC): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646265/iis-doesnt-start-error-code-c0000142

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET strange compilation error!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817870/asp-net-strange-compilation-error)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already tried changing the Application Pool Identity (mine was set to NetworkService, changing it to ApplicationPoolIdentity hasn't helped). The application name is set, and has not been changed to an empty string.

Comment: You may want to check the event viewer, it should contain more details on which DLL is faulting.

Comment: Replace the machine's hard drive soon.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not following you. Are you suggesting that I replace the physical hard drive on my laptop, or the virtual hard drive used by my virtual machine? I've made sure that there is enough disk space on the virtual hard drive (a good 23GB free), I've run chkdsk and I've defragmented it (the same goes for my physical hard drive, that was actually replaced a couple of weeks ago. I had the problem on my old physical hard drive as well).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem ... i stopped my app the in the app pool i recycled the app pool related to the app it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much , I had a similar problem and I can confirm (After all the others attempts) only the 'repair' execution of the Framework 3.5  fixed the problem.

Reinstall (repair) .NET framework (the only solution that works for me)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue happen after deploying with version 16.9.3 of VS 2019. I deployed to three machines all VMs running windows server 2012 and only one had the problem. Tried several of the solutions above with no luck. I finally tried rebooting the server with the issue and that solved the problem for me.