# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When  built build the solution,has no errors.What this means?
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\531418d8\19a5ce64_c03fce01\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\170ee7f7\003d348b_acaccb01\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\a22bb0b4\519f7cc5_1b42ce01\MvcPager.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\0510f5a7\457139f5_1b42ce01\ZPMH.Infra.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\57198f34\519f7cc5_1b42ce01\Omu.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\476d065b\6830d000_7a79ce01\ZPMH.WebUI.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\0772e69c\317b75c5_1b42ce01\log4net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\cddec2f6\75312793_1b42ce01\Castle.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\a76687c5\e34d03d5_9952ce01\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\87353a58\003d348b_acaccb01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\ae9822fc\003d348b_acaccb01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\94b823bb\1c2700e1_1b42ce01\Omu.AwesomeMvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\89b68d6e\75312793_1b42ce01\Castle.Windsor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\c7d8fcd3\1c2700e1_1b42ce01\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\eca8993f\003d348b_acaccb01\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\b687bd36\16db3793_1b42ce01\ZPMH.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\a06d981a\b6793593_1b42ce01\ZPMH.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\26a6be88\003d348b_acaccb01\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\9b8e1639\004c56d6_bcaccb01\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\c501a63c\b6793593_1b42ce01\Omu.ValueInjecter.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\assembly\dl3\f591894d\56183393_1b42ce01\Omu.Encrypto.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\App_global.asax.dsnvexll.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\App_global.asax.dsnvexll.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edafaa7b\1616764b\App_global.asax.dsnvexll.1.cs"

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: Woha! That's a lot of code. Can you maybe explain more what you are doing instead of dropping a massive amount of unreadable code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686254/the-compiler-failed-with-error-code-1073741502-sharepoint-2010-sp1-running-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: according to [this interesting post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2012/09/19/c-compiler-or-visual-basic-net-compilers-fail-with-error-code-1073741502-when-generating-assemblies-for-your-asp-net-site.aspx), it could be due to a heap exhaustion. You can solve by either configuring your website to use the AppPoolIdentity account or using a dedicated user account for that specific application pool.

Comment: THX,I reset iis and create a new app pool  it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, this phenomenon happened because some dll refering conflicted, so delete exist dlls of the release environment, then release again, maybe solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the application pool identity from "Local system" to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"
Apparently there was a permission error with my local system that csharp compiler (csc.exe) could not access some resources and source codes.

In order to change your AppPool identity follow steps given here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: You should include relevant information from the link as part of your answer to prevent future dead links.